# how to make runtime.getruntime().exec(String command) return a boolean value?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to use runtime.getruntime().exec(String command) to return a value so that I can make the system decide on executing it again or not.
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

`Runtime.exec` returns a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), process has a method called `waitFor`, which will wait for the running process to terminate and return.

`Process` has a method called `exitVaue`, which returns an `int` returning the exit state of the program.  Convention suggests that `0` is an indication of a normal termination, but this might be contextual to the program you are running.

You would need to...

1. Know what is a valid exit value for the process your are running
2. Check the `exitValue` returned by the instance of `Process` against the known valid exit values.

**Things to note...**

- Generally, you should be consuming the `InputStream`s (input and error) of the `Process`, as failing to do so can cause some processes to stall
- [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is generally a better solution as has better functionality when it comes to dealing with multiple parameters for the command, has redirection and can even determine the starting directory context for the command...

Answer (score 3):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process process = runtime.exec(args);
       InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String line;

       System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
           Arrays.toString(args));

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

it returns Process that is what it will return , it up to you to deduce if it ran successfully or not and that depend on what your process is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

> runtime.getruntime().exec(String command)  method create a native process and return an instance of a subclass of Process that can be used to control the process and obtain information about it. The class Process provides methods for performing input from the process, performing output to the process, waiting for the process to complete, checking the exit status of the process, and destroying (killing) the process and It has one method exitValue and it returns 0 mean it's a normal termination

```
Reference :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html
```